# Index exceeds matrix dimension when applied to an array of values

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I wrote the following problem in Matlab to get the first 3 digits of a number.

Let x be a real number.

```
function [y]=mifl(x) % mifl=my float
  s=num2str(x);
  y=sscanf(s(1:4),'%f');
end
```

So function mifl returns the first 3 digits of a number. 
For example,

```
mifl(pi)=3.14
```

But when I tried to apply this function to all the values of the vector v I got "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". I can't figure out why.

I used

```
v=linspace(0.1, 99.9, 1000);
w=[]
  for i=1:5
    w(i)=mifl(v(i))
  end
```

That's when I get the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions".

At the end, what I want is, given a vector

```
v=linspace(0.1, 99.9, 1000);
```

to get a vector

```
w=[mifl(0.1),...mifl(99.9)]
```

Comment: Just a question, do you mean you want to return the first 3 digits or is what you mean that you want 3 significat digits? Such that an input 1234567 will return 1230000.

Comment: I'm just considering numbers between 0.1 and 99.9 (those are all the possible values for this problem), so I think the function is well defined.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to criticize. I apologize if it sounded that way. My point was that in the case you want 3 significant digits, there is a Matlab solution for this. See my answer.

Comment: Oh, no need to apologize at all. Thanks for your answer. The program returns the number x (for example pi) into a number in the floating point number system with base 10, precision 3 and exponents between -1 and 1 (in the example 3.14). There is an error message in the function for numbers that are out of that range.

Comment: Also I need to consider rounding by chop, so, for example, 2.347 and 2.341 become 2.34.

Comment: Ok I understand. Currently I cannot provide a better solution. However it seems a waste to go through a string every time. The memory may not even be of the same size. matlab should improve the `floor` and `ceil` to work the same as round for truncation. However, due to the former comments I get some questions. It is not a part of the question, but the purpose of the truncation to 3 significant digits is not completely clear. It is not really a trunkation in number of bits. This makes me wonder if there are some reason you want this, which can be done simpler. Would you mind explaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because you are specifying a number in your function that **doesn't have** three significant digits.  Specifically, try `0.1` from your vector.  This doesn't have 3 digits and so you get an out of bounds error because you're assuming it does.

As such, in your function, check the length of the string and ensure that there are 4 characters to extract.  If not, then get whatever is available:

```
function [y]=mifl(x) % mifl=my float
  s=num2str(x);
  m = min(numel(s), 4); %// Change
  y=sscanf(s(1:m),'%f');
end
```

If you try the above, your code should now work.

---

I'd like to also suggest that you **pre-allocate** your arrays before populating them for speed.

Specifically:

```
v=linspace(0.1, 99.9, 1000);
w=zeros(numel(v),1);
for i=1:numel(v)
   w(i)=mifl(v(i));
end
```

`w` is initialized to be an array of 0s that is as long as `v`, then we'll go through each value in `v` and call `mifl`, then store this result in the corresponding location in `w`.

Comment: @Fawcett512 - My pleasure.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matlabs `rand` function.

```
y = round(x,3,'significant');
```

This will return the first 3 significant digits of each number in a vector `x`. This code will also be easy for another person to comprehend since round is a built in Matlab function, which is used for rounding. The argument `'significant'` should be clear enough. This will also work for numbers larger than 100, which makes it more general. That is of course if it was 3 significant digits you were after and not the first three digits in the number. In that case this will not work. The number 1001 would then be 1000 and not 100, which your solution would give.